# rails best way to handle optional parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a list of stocks when the user logs in (default parameters). This smells like an index action. However, I will also make a form for the user to select the market capitalization of the stocks (that is to refine the universe). The submission of the form will send parameters to some action (I am not sure if I should use the same index action) and then do an ajax update of the list.  This ajax doesn't do anything to the database, it just updates the parameters for the database query.

The first time the user visits the site, they will see the default parameters for the query, but I also want them to be able to change the parameters later and renew the list according to their parameter through ajax.

Comment: If you think in terms of resources, query or no, you're still just showing a collection of the stock resource.  Index should be fine. Don't get too wound up around DRY. Our rabid DRY fan at work (we nicknamed him 'Parched' if that gives you any hint) tends to run into 'analysis paralysis' around the topic. A little refactoring when the code gets a little 'damp' is to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, a list of stocks sure sounds like an index action. Do you mean that you want to filter the list depending on some form input?

You can make the form send to the index action with a get method, and in your controller, just read the params, and query your @stocks however you want your filter to work.

This is the non-Ajax solution, so users without Javascript will be happy. When you get this working, you can easily AJAXify it.

Comment: That's exactly what I turned out doing. It works very DRY and clean and, most importantly, makes me feel good looking at clean code. Thanks